# OOTB Checkout page has "Define order date"; what is this and how do I remove it

Tags: checkout, magento-1.9, billing

I'm using Magento community 1.9.  On the Magento out of the box checkout page in the billing information section is a "Define order date" field the user can put any date into.

What is this?  How can I remove it?  I don't remember seeing it in v1.8

Thanks

Comment: I found the code in an extension called "Sitewards B2B Professional".  Even though I have this extension disabled, the define order date still shows up, so I uninstalled it from magento connect and got errors on both front & back end.  Had to reinstall it.  I have a support call into the company now.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Magento.SE!

I have thoroughly reviewed the codebase and the demo store at http://enterprise-demo.user.magentotrial.com/checkout/onepage/ and could not find evidence of a 'Define Order Date' field at all in Magento 1.9CE/1.14EE, or any prior version.

Some troubleshooting tips:

- Disable all local modules by editing the `app/etc/local.xml` file and changing the node to  `<disable_local_modules>true</disable_local_modules>`
- Revert to the default theme (base/default) and see if the issue persists
- Install a from-scratch version of 1.9CE with the demo data and see if the field continues to display.

The only "date" field that shows by default in billing information step of checkout is the Date of Birth field. These are configurable, too, by editing `System > Configuration > Customer Configuration > Address Templates`

Otherwise please review the standard debug procedure here: https://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-debug-process/